# What is the name of the post variable what is sending from paypal webhooks?

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-webhooks

Paypal webhooks send me a post variable, but whats the name from that?
I can't found anything.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: yes i have. But i can't found this. There is written, that i get the response in json. I'll read this post, but how can i do this without the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

The posted variables depend on the event triggered. To actually see the post sent by PayPal , Follow the below steps :

```
1. Go to developer.paypal.com--> Dashboard and login . 
2. In left move to "WebHooks Simulator" and put your url you want to receive the post to after selecting the event type and it will show you the data posted after clicking on submit .
```

You will see something like below :

[image]

Comment: i use that already.
But if i work on my webhook-url with that post, i don't get any information.
I'll read that post-variable. But whats the name?
$_POST[....]? 
I don't found any information in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

When a webhook is sent, it sends headers as well as a payload.  That documentation is spread between the two links below.  What's not explained very well is the actual contents of the "resource" field.  If for example the webhook is for a sale event type, then the contents of resource is the same as getting the info from GET /v1/payments/sale/

First link explains the main payload.  Second link explains the headers.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#retrieve-a-webhook-event
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/

Answer (score 0):

```
$bodyReceived = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to offer some context with your code suggestion. Please see here for [How to Write a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow.